# Adding custom CSS to Magento Homepage

Tags: html, css, magento, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a css file to my CMS homepage by going to `CMS > Pages > Home > Design` then updating the Layout XML however it keeps adding in /base to the url to show the following:

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addJs">
 <script>nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js</script>
</action>
<action method="addCss">
<script>../bootstrap/theme_name/css/nivo-slider.css
</script></action>
</reference>
```

which outputs the following in view source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/frontend/base/default/bootstrap/theme_name/css/nivo-slider.css" media="all" />
```

I've tried ../ and adding in the absolute link however it just adds it after the /base/

Is there a way I can override the theme trying to add in /base/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `theme_name` is your active theme, try to replace `<action method="addCss">...</action>` with this node:

```
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/nivo-slider.css</file></action>
```

Base folder is loaded due to the magento fallback. It searchs last in base folder, that's why base is added.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - Using addItem instead of addCss did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

try with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/nivo-slider.css</file></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

hope this will sure help you.